# Get completion event from default warning dialog?

Tags: ios, alert, default, uialertcontroller

what I thought should be simple, doesn't seem so simple...

I have a BT application, so if BT is off on launch, the default warning "Turn On Bluetooth to Allow...", which has the options "Settings" and "OK" as the options. Since this is a default dialog, how do I get the button index clicked?

I am working with the iOS 8 SDK, so I assume this dialog is making use of the new UIAlertController, which now uses a completion block instead of a delegate method.

Comment: what do you mean by "I assume" that it uses UIAlertController? Haven't you got the code? Which specific use should the answer cover: UIAlertView or UIAlertController? UIAlertView is deprecated but still works on iOS 8...

Comment: It's a default warning supplied by the OS, so no, I do not have the code, that is why I am assuming it is using the UIAlertController.

Comment: Now it is clear. I do not think you can tap into the system presenting an alert... that alert come from the OS, not from your app, so you have no access to it. Maybe if you clarify what you want to do after knowing which button has been pressed, the community will be able to help further...

Comment: @sergio- This is for a framework to handle the connection to the device, I don't want to keep annoying the user, "Turn On Bluetooth", so I made use of applicationDidBecomeActive, applicationWillResignActive, and applicationWillEnterForeground local notifications to help distinguish between leaving the app(Settings), or just pressing OK. This also seems to work nicely for when the app is running normally, and the user leaves the app. It would be really nice to determine if Bluetooth is on using the EA framework. I can use CB, however, why link the library, all i'm using it for is to check power